# command prompt appears than immediately disappears

Tags: python-2.7, command-prompt

I encountered this problem after following a python tutorial on Youtube about creating text files. The instructor had us type in the following code to start:

```
def createFile(dest):
   print dest

if__name__ == '__main__':
   createFile('ham')
   raw_input('done!')
```

We had created a folder on the desktop to store the file 'ham' in.  But when I double clicked on 'ham' the command prompt window popped on then in a flash it popped off.  I am an obvious beginner and I don't know what is going on. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Don't double click your file. It will run, then the command prompt will close, as you're seeing. Open a command prompt (Start > Run > `cmd`), `cd` to the directory where your file is, and run the python script from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can open  command prompt then navigate to python interpreter
directory and run your program by typing python /diretory/to/your/program.py for
example if you have a program named test.py in the directory c:/python  and you want to 
run it and you have python interpreter installed in C:/python2.x/ directory
then you should open command prompt and type in
    `cd c:\python2.x\`
then you should type 
    `python c:/python/test.py`
and perfectly it will work
showing you your program output .